# Video player with millisecond resolution

Tags: video, media-player

Are there any free-download-able media players out there that supports sub-second seek/display? I wish to do a more in-depth analysis of a .avi file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are more interested in frame analyzing than in playing, you might want to try [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/).

Answer (score 0):

[Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) allows frame stepping.

Comment: So does Windows Media Player and probably most video players out there :-)

Comment: meh... I thought he would've tried that already.

Comment: can i assume the frame-steps are consistant for a particular file?

Comment: @Johannes Rössel How does WMP provide this functionality?

Comment: @Joey Where is the option?

Comment: Dan, barlop: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/21/10177190.aspx

Comment: @joey nice, I don't see an enhancements option right clicking the volume control(i'm in WMP9, may be relevant) but I see clicking play while holding control.. or holding control and tapping space(tapping space being like hitting play). both do brief steps possibly frame by frame. great link.

Comment: @Joey by the way, you addressed that "Dan, barlop" in a way such that neither of us got notification of your reply! I just happened to revisit the question

Comment: @DanNeely see now!

Comment: barlop: I did, intentionally. I refuse to go with the stupid @. If that makes communication difficult, so be it; it is much easier on my eyes, though. Besides, if I remember correctly, only the first @ed person would be notified anyway. As for WMP 9 ... yikes. I have WMP 12 here and the OS is already two years old.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have my Dell in front of me but I had this problem a few weeks ago. You can right click in Windows Media Player and adjust the "seek speed" or something like that. Then you can step through frame by frame. Or download Quicktime player and use the arrow keys.

Comment: Where is the option?

Comment: I think the user was thinking of the "Play Speed" settings, which are unrelated to the issue.